# D type qualifier is meaningless on cast type

Tags: c, eclipse, arm, embedded, cortex-m

what is the meaning of "D type qualifier is meaningless on cast type at this line of code"

```
    (*((volatile RCC_t * const)0x400FE060)).USESYSDIV = 1;
```

and how to solve it?

Comment: There are only two type qualifiers, `volatile` and `const`.  One is meaningless and can/should be removed.

Comment: @FiddlingBits: `restrict` and `_Atomic` are also qualifiers.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Sorry, I meant in the OP's statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`volatile RCC_t * const` says the pointer (not the thing it points to) is `const`. But this is for a **value**, which is just a result used in an expression. Qualifiers like `const` are properties of **objects** in memory. So it serves no purpose in this cast.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is the `const`, which says that the **pointer** itself does not change. But since it is the value of an expression, then it by definition cannot change, it just **is**.

It is the same as casting `42` to a `const unsigned char`:

```
printf("%hhu", (const unsigned char)42);
```

but how would you could the value of `42` change anyway?

Comment: Re “how … could the value of 42 change anyway?”: Add `volatile`. Then it can change in ways unknown to the compiler, right in the middle of an expression. 